# Does OpenTest support Implicit Waits?

Tags: webdriverwait, opentest

Does OpenTest support specifying implicit waits for element location or page loading?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use implicit waits in OpenTest. All keywords know how to wait for the UI elements they interact with. Behind the scenes, OpenTest uses explicit waits, which you can customize, when necessary, by setting the `explicitWaitSec` argument for a test action (the default is 10 seconds). For example:

```
- description: Verify that element is visible
  action: org.getopentest.selenium.AssertElementVisible
  args:
    locator: { id: my_element }
    explicitWaitSec: 20
```